# javascript bind & trigger events to loading elements

Tags: jquery

I'm loading a massive page, with tons of text, so it takes a while for it all to come in.  Specifically, it's a large set bar graphs representing books, each with dozens of excerpts hidden in popups.   I'd like the user to be able to interact with the bars as they come in rather than waiting until the page is fully loaded.

Usually, for dynamically created elements, .on() would do the trick, but it seems to work for the elements already loaded during the page load, and none subsequent.  Is there an effective way to bind an event to a currently loaded item (before entire page loaded) as well as all matching elements as the page continues to load?

Could I use .on() and .off() to bind and unbind elements as things are loaded? - would I be able to detect when each book is loaded, or have to setup a timed looping interval triggering the function, then double checking to see if the next element (book) has loaded?

I'll be able to upload it in a few days in case that description wasn't clear.
Thanks for your help!

David